# What are go.mod.tmp files?

Tags: go

I am building with Go1.13 with go modules on and i keep noticing these new `go.mod`s popping up from time to time, usually after adding a new dependency, for e.g. `go.mod199651888.tmp`

What are these files? Can I get rid of them?

Comment: Temporaries. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Those are temporary files used by the Go Module system, as you may guess by the `.tmp` extension. You can get rid of them and shouldn't care much about them.